# configuring a L2 transparent wireless bridge on WAN side of router

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan, wireless-bridge

I'm configuring a Layer 2 wireless bridge and found that my router (ASUS RT-N66U) is unable to create VLANs on WAN for managing the bridge radios from within the LAN.  In case that's unclear, the bridge's two radios are between my ISP's cable modem (not a router) and my router.  (Note: I can manage the radios "locally" via direct ethernet cable connection as needed.)

Since the bridge is transparent I think this can work, although I'm not sure about all the settings:
[screen shot of the radio's manual on IP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax0a7.png)

I will set the IP to be a private IPv4 (RFC1918) address, leave subnet on default, but then am unsure.  I believe the gateway for the radio near my router is the other radio, but what about the radio near the modem?  And I'm not sure about the DHCP settings.  DNS servers can be the usual suspects, and I believe the Domain Name can be blank since I don't have a server within my network.

EDIT: my guess is that I should enable DHCP on the radio nearest the cable modem (E31U2V1 DOCSIS 3.1 eMTA) so its managed by the modem's DNS.  The radio on the other end of the bridge should have its gateway set to the other radio or be DHCP too.  Enabling DHCP greys out all settings but the Domain Name (which is "the operator's mgmt domain name, which "may be configured for DNS", but I don't have a server in my network).  Here's the updated IP config screen: [screen shot of radio's IP config screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdcLE.png) And a screen shot of the manual's descriptions for the items: [picture of the manual's item descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF77K.png)

Comment: You do know you are taking a duplex connection and making it simplex? This is non ideal.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain your comment.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - the radios handle transmission themselves via OFDM, so are able to carry on bi-directional coms on the same frequencies by "stuttering" in essence.  I cannot change this via configuration.

Comment: What's the hardware model of the 900Mhz L2 bridges? OFDM doesn't make it bidirectional, even if it was sold as MIMO. The MIMO part just means spatial streams i.e more bandwidth in either direction. Simplex means it can send or receive, but not simultaneously. I'm not aware of any consumer equipment that does do full-duplex. It's usually fancy enterprise gear that can, very expensive, and usually licenced. Note- even 802.11ac mu-mimo is kind of a lie, as it doesn't actually achieve duplex. It would need separate frequencies on rx/tx to do so.

Comment: Cambium 450 radios operating on the 900MHz frequency (unlicensed).  Here's what the manual says about duplex coms: "The system uses Time Division Duplexing (TDD) – one channel alternately transmits and receives rather than using one channel for transmitting and a second channel for receiving. The radio link operates on a single frequency channel in each direction using TDD. The AP operates in TDMA mode to service multiple SMs. To accomplish TDD, the AP/BHM must provide sync to its SM/BHS."

Comment: Although Cambium isn't "consumer" grade, its the only mfg producing 900MHz equipment.  I tried Ubiquiti's 2.4GHz radios but they were unable to penetrate the 1/3mi of forest between the radios.  So I was forced to Cambium.

Comment: That's pretty decent for nlos. What kind of throughput are you achieving?

Comment: Haven't deployed yet; finishing up the configs today.  LinkPlanner estimates I could achieve between 10MBPS down/up and almost 20MBPS down/up (so almost 40MBPS aggregate) depending on antenna heights.  

If that works as planned I will be prioritizing forest thinning along the bridge route to improve bandwidth.  Its a 20yo 2nd growth forest in need of thinning anyways.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the gateway for the radio near my router is the other radio, but what about the radio near the modem?

No. The devices are supposed to work as *layer-2 bridges*, which means they forward packets without actually looking at the IP (layer-3) header. So neither of them needs a layer-3 gateway to perform the task, and neither of them acts as a layer-3 gateway (router) for any other device either.

The only use for IP configuration on bridges is when they act as *hosts* – e.g. when you connect to their config webpage, or when they sync clocks from NTP, or when they download firmware updates. In this case they should use the same gateway as all other hosts on the same subnet.

But because your bridges are kind of in a subnet of their own, using RFC1918 addresses yet placed on the WAN side (between your router and the ISP), there actually *isn't* any valid gateway for them to use. Just fill in some nonexistent address, or even leave the gateway field empty.

*(This wouldn't be the case if your router was able to create VLANs on the WAN side – in that case, your router would act as a gateway if necessary... but as already mentioned, it is not necessary.)*

Comment: thank you 1686 - that clears up a lot - I will test your recommendation.  Sorry I can't publicly vote on your answer yet.